# Create a trigger that subtracts 1 from a column in another table

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I need a trigger that subtracts 1 in a column called quantity of a table, I already researched a lot but I can't find a solution (I know it's simple), I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE product 
(
    product_id number,
    price number,
    quantity number
)

CREATE TABLE sale 
(
    sale_id number,
    client_id number,
    product_id number
)
```

The value of the quantity column of the product table starts with 0, let's suppose that I have 50 in the quantity of a product, I need that when there is a sale the quantity of this product drops to 49, can you guys help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `sale` table misses crucial information: number (quantity) of items sold. So:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE product (
  2    product_id number,
  3    price      number,
  4    quantity   number
  5  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE sale (
  2   sale_id    number,
  3   client_id  number,
  4   product_id number,
  5   quantity   number           --> missing
  6  );

Table created.
```

Trigger:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_ai_sale
  2    after insert on sale
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    update product p set
  6      p.quantity = p.quantity - :new.quantity
  7      where p.product_id = :new.product_id;
  8  end;
  9  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing: starting quantity for product = 1 is 50:

```
SQL> insert into product (product_id, price, quantity) values (1, 100, 50);

1 row created.
```

Let's sell 1 item:

```
SQL> insert into sale (sale_id, client_id, product_id, quantity) values (1, 1, 1, 1);

1 row created.
```

Quantity is now 49:

```
SQL> select * from product;

PRODUCT_ID      PRICE   QUANTITY
---------- ---------- ----------
         1        100         49

SQL>
```